# Responsive Web forms/ Website for Internet Explorer 8

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, ie8-compatibility-mode

I am trying to create a responsive website that will fit in, In any browser and screen resolution. I though that would be easy but it lead me to my wrong impression. Specially that most of the future user that i will be dealing with is using Internet Explorer 8.

My problem is when i zoom in or re - size the window, I come up with this.
Please click the link to see the photo.

[Tinypic image](http://i57.tinypic.com/108a0iv.png)

Here is my css and HTML markup.

**CSS**

```
*
            {
                padding:0;
                margin:0;
            }

            html
            {
                overflow:auto;
            }

            html, body
            {
                margin:auto;
                width:100%;
                height:100%;
                overflow:auto;
                margin:auto;
                background:#eee;
            }

            .placeholder
            {
                color:#aaa;
            }

            .main
            {
                width:100%;
                height:100%;
                overflow:auto;

            }

            .nav
            {
                width:9%;
                min-width:9%;
                background:#111;
                text-align: center;
                position:absolute;
            }

            .panel
            {
                min-height:100%;
            }

            .nav ul
            {
                margin-top:110%;
            }

            .nav ul a
            {
                text-decoration:none;
                border:none;
            }

            a img
            {
                border:0;
                outline:none;

            }

            a:active, a:focus
            {
                outline:none;
                border:none;
            }


            .nav li
            {
                display:block;
                float:center;
                color:#fff;
                text-align:center;
            }


            .nav #logout, #add, #view, #setting
            {
                border-bottom:1px solid #3a3a3a;
            }

            .nav #add
            {
                border-top:1px solid #3a3a3a;
            }

            .nav li:hover
            {
                background:#333;

            }

            .nav li img
            {
                padding:20px 0 20px 0;
                height:55%;
                width:55%;
            }

            .nav_text
            {
                color:#777;
                font-family:helvetica;
                font-size: 70%;
                text-align:center;
                margin-top:-10px;
                text-indent:-5px;
                margin-bottom:5px;
            }

            .main_bar
            {
                display:inline-block;
                margin-right:3%;
                background:#fff;
                float:right;
                width:75%;
                border-bottom:10px solid #3498db;
                margin-top:10px;
                background:rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
                box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.9) 0 1px 4px 0;
                border-bottom:10px solid #0dabc9;
                /*zoom: 1;
                filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#c0c0c0, Strength=8, Direction=0),
                       progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#c0c0c0, Strength=8, Direction=90),
                       progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#c0c0c0, Strength=8, Direction=180),
                       progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#c0c0c0, Strength=8, Direction=300);
                */
            }

            .tool_bar
            {
                width:10%;
                background:#333;
                height:50%;
                float:right;
                position:relative;
                margin-right:2%;
                margin-top:10px;
                border-top:30px solid #3498db;
            }

            .second_bar
            {
                display:block;
                margin-right:15%;
                background:#fff;
                float:right;
                width:75%;
                border-bottom:10px solid #3498db;
                margin-top:10px;
                background:rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
                box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,0.9) 0 1px 4px 0;
                border-bottom:10px solid #0dabc9;
                zoom:1;
                filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#c0c0c0, Strength=8, Direction=0),
                       progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#c0c0c0, Strength=8, Direction=90),
                       progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#c0c0c0, Strength=8, Direction=180),
                       progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#c0c0c0, Strength=8, Direction=300);
            }

            .draft
            {   
                position:relative;
                font-weight:bold;
                font-size:11px;
                font-family:Helvetica;
                color:#555;
                padding:4px;

            }

            .draft span
            {
                position:absolute;
                display:inline-block;
                width:25px;
                border:1px solid #2980b9;
                padding:5px;
                border-radius:3px 0 0 3px;
                /*background:#bdc3c7;*/
                background:#2980b9;
            }

            .draft span img
            {
                vertical-align:bottom;
                width:16px;
                height:16px;
                padding:0px 5px;

            }

            .draft input[type=textbox]
            {
                /*position:absolute;*/
                border:1px solid #b0b0b0;
                border-radius:0 5px 5px 0;
                padding:5px;
                margin-left:-1px;
                width:155px;
                padding-left:45px;
            }


            .draft input[type=textbox]:focus
            {
                outline:none;
            }
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
                <div class = "main">
                <div class = "nav panel">
                <ul>
                <li id = "add"><a href = "#"><img src = "images/add.png"><p class = "nav_text">ADD</p></a></li>
                <li id = "view"><a href = "#"><img src = "images/add.png"><p class = "nav_text">VIEW</p></a></li>
                <li id = "setting"><a href = "#"><img src = "images/add.png"><p class = "nav_text">MAINTENANCE</p></a></li>
                <li id = "logout"><a href = "#"><img  src = "images/add.png"><p class = "nav_text">LOGOUT</p></a></li>
                </ul>
                </div>
                <div class = "tool_bar"></div>
                <div class = "main_bar">
                    <table class = "tabledraft">
                        <tr>
                        <td class = "draft"><span><img src = "images/adver.png"></span><input type = "textbox" placeholder = "Platform"></td>
                        <td class = "draft"><span><img src = "images/adver.png"></span><input type = "textbox" placeholder = "Platform"></td>
                        <td class = "draft"><span><img src = "images/adver.png"></span><input type = "textbox" placeholder = "Platform"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td class = "draft"><span><img src = "images/adver.png"></span><input type = "textbox" placeholder = "Platform"></td>
                        <td class = "draft"><span><img src = "images/adver.png"></span><input type = "textbox" placeholder = "Platform"></td>
                        <td class = "draft"><span><img src = "images/adver.png"></span><input type = "textbox" placeholder = "Platform"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td class = "draft"><span><img src = "images/adver.png"></span><input type = "textbox" placeholder = "Platform"></td>
                        <td class = "draft"><span><img src = "images/adver.png"></span><input type = "textbox" placeholder = "Platform"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td class = "draft"><span><img src = "images/adver.png"></span><input type = "textbox" placeholder = "Platform"></td>
                        <td class = "draft"><span><img src = "images/adver.png"></span><input type = "textbox" placeholder = "Platform"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>

            </div>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: @Rider here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/GN7bP/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen the CSS, most of them are in % like width, but not this

```
.draft span
        {
            position:absolute;
            display:inline-block;
            width:25px;
            border:1px solid #2980b9;
            padding:5px;
            border-radius:3px 0 0 3px;
            /*background:#bdc3c7;*/
            background:#2980b9;
        }
```

where width is 25px, what exactly happens here is , when zoom-in or Out is done, 25px will remain as fixed, what i suggest is try to add it px to %, to your requirement then you wont be having any problem

**NOTE**

When you use css to div or td make sure the parent class is in % or px, it depend on that how you write css to chill class, its always to manage in %

check these 3 images from Chrome,IE(11) and FF

[image: Chrome]

[image: FF]

[image: IE]

```
  <div id="Main">sdfasfa
```

```
        <td class = "draft"><span><img src = "images/adver.png"></span><input type = "textbox" placeholder = "Platform"></td>

        <td class = "draft"><span><img src = "images/adver.png"></span><input type = "textbox" placeholder = "Platform"></td>
        <td class = "draft"><span><img src = "images/adver.png"></span><input type = "textbox" placeholder = "Platform"></td>
        </tr>
```

**and css for above is**

```
#Main
{
Border:1px solid red;
height:50%;
width:70%;
background-color:silver;
}
.draft
{   

font-weight:bold;
font-size:11px;
font-family:Helvetica;
color:#555;
padding:1%;
 border:1px solid black;
width:20%;
}

.draft span
{

display:inline-block;
width:15%;
border:1px solid #2980b9;
padding:1%;
border-radius:3px 0 0 3px;
/*background:#bdc3c7;*/
background:#2980b9;
}

.draft span img
{
vertical-align:bottom;
width:5%;
height:5%;
padding:0px 5px;

}

.draft input[type=textbox]
{
/*position:absolute;*/
border:1px solid #b0b0b0;
border-radius:0 5px 5px 0;
padding:2%;
margin-left:1px;
width:65%;
padding-left:5%;
}


.draft input[type=textbox]:focus
{
    outline:none;
}
```

Comment: Hi x'tian I have modified your fiddle with very sample code, hope this is what you need , let me know   "http://jsfiddle.net/Manjuboyz/vJS4m/10/", I guess have some issue with fiddle, please check the code I have pasted to the top, use it on fiddle and see

Comment: here is my updated fiddle so you will know what i have with. http://jsfiddle.net/GN7bP/8/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Manjuboyz/GN7bP/32/  changed to your fiddle, if zoomed it wont cross its border, even zoom-in, font has to be changed based on @media query

Comment: Yes i will @Manjuboyz. but I'm having a problem again and that is when i larger the size of the image. the span is seperated with the textbox.

Comment: yeah, That's  why I said on last comment, you need to change the font size, that is the culprit, the reason it is separated because of the size of the font while zooming more, you can see the font varies, so if you used @media query, to maintain the size when zooming out, it fits as expected

Comment: No Im talking to the IMAGE @Manjuboyz not the font. is the role same with the image and font? :) thank you.

Comment: Let me explain you, the tag you used inside td, all 3 css values like, span, img and class=draft are in same td, when zooming to larger will collapse or may be merge, if i were you what i gonna do is, will create a div, inside div will create two more div of same height but different width(one for img and one for textbox), later i will add img to left div and text box to right, so that whenever you zoom-in or Out, it wont bother you much, if possible to change, do it in that way(make sure css properties should be in % for nice result), all the best

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, gone for lunch ;), and here is the fiddle which might help you, and it wont merge or go out of border how much ever you zoom it http://jsfiddle.net/Manjuboyz/vJS4m/50/